# c: Отличия функций basename

Tags: c

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему на этом ресурсе http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=basename&category=3&russian=0 в примере снизу , память освобождается ?
А здесь http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html - нет

Нужно ли на самом деле освобождать память ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю, что это только пример использования функции `basename`, который не предполагает освобождение памяти после ее вызова.

Память нужно освобождать после функции `strdup`, которая ее динамически выделяет под копию строки, передаваемой в параметре.

Comment: Ну так примеры идентичные, и ПРАВИЛЬНЫМ будет в этих примерах ВООБЩе, освобождать память или нет ?

Comment: @Andreyua После `strdup` освобождать память нужно.

Comment: А можете навести пример кода с basename где освобождать память не нужно ?

Comment: После dirname/basename память освобождать не нужно, но в примере также используется strdup, который создает копию строки, выделяя для нее память. Эту память освобождать нужно.

Comment: Чтобы не выделять память (и не удалять ее впоследствии), не используйте strdup, а передавайте исходную строку. Только учтите, что это можно сделать лишь один раз, так как функции dirname/basename изменяют передаваемую ей строку (чтобы избежать изменения path в примерах и делаются копии).

Comment: @Andreyua Да, конечно. Например, `char name[] = "/foo/bar.txt"; printf(basename(name));`.

Comment: Я так понял strdup делается из-за того что в реальных задачах пути всегда отличаются, то есть в принципе , говоря обобща, память освобождать в большинстве случаев нужно ?

Comment: strdup делается для того, чтобы не менялся исходный path (так как dirname и pathname меняют свой аргумент) (в данном случае, так как строка статическая, это вообще приведет к ошибке). А память нужно освобождать не в большинстве случаев, а тогда, когда она выделяется. И только.